# Multiple Drives in RAID with fstab configuration not mounting correctly

Tags: server, 16.04, mount, raid, mdadm

This is new territory for me in linux, so I hope I'm just missing something.

I have 1 SSD as the OS drive (has the swap space and all other partitions configured when Ubuntu was initially installed), 6 drives, each in a 2 device RAID 1 configuration, and 2 more, with 2 partitions each in another RAID 1 configuration.

I set them up using mdadm, and when I set up the RAIDs I wanted them to have text names (not just md1, etc). I decided to name them with the user's name who is going to be using the drives. However, mdadm would prompt me that `/dev/mdjohn` was not valid, and to try `/dev/md/john` instead. I did this, and after a reboot, `/dev/md/` contains all of the user's names prefixed with the computers name (in this case FILESERVER). So the new RAID I just made is actually `/dev/md/FILESERVER:john`. Not the cleanest, but ok.

Now, to auto-mount this to /mnt/john I added it to `fstab` by calling `/dev/md/FILESERVER:john`. This was working fine. When I got to the last pair of drives, which have two partitions in 2 RAIDs, things got sticky. The first partition is `FILESERVER:shared` and the second is `FILESERVER:private`. When I added these to `fstab` (specifically `FILESERVER:shared`), the server will fail to boot. When checking the logs on the server, it says that the shared drive timed out when mounting.

If I leave it out and mount it manually, it takes a second, but not anywhere near the ~2 minutes it timesout during boot. My solution to this was to replace the `FILESERVER:name` calls in `fstab` with the md# listed in `lsblk`. For instance, `/mnt/john` is a mount of `/dev/md127`, `/mnt/shared/` is a mount of `/dev/md123`, etc. The problem with this approach, is that the md#s shuffle every boot. So one boot /mnt/john is pointed to his drives, but another boot, it's pointed to the shared drives, etc. (this creates an instance where the `/mnt/john` folder is owned by user doe, and `/mnt/doe` is owned by user doe. The users can access their counterparts folders, which still have their correct files, but this makes things confusing and prevents my ssh starting folder rules to not behave correctly.

How can I get the drives to mount to the correct folders every time, without timing out on boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by using UUID.

I ran:

```
sudo blkid
```

To list all of my devices. I then mapped out which `/dev/md#` was who's drive, and updated `/etc/fstab` to replace `/dev/md#` with `UUID=long-UUID-string-here`.

Apparently, the `/dev/md#` will change everytime a device is added/removed (or every boot, in my case) while the `UUID` is static.

More information can be found on the [Ubuntu Fstab Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)